# Disable PyTest Recursion Checking?

Tags: recursion, pytest

When I run PyTest, I get some tests failing with

```
....
!!! Recursion detected (same locals & position)
```

However when I run the tests manually, I see that there is no infinite recursion.  My code does do some weird stuff that probably trick's pytest's recursion detector.

Is there a way to disable recursion checking for certain tests?

I'm running PyTest 3.0.1

Comment: That line [only gets printed if a `RecursionError` (or `RuntimeError` on Py3.4 or below) is thrown](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/_pytest/_code/code.py#L606-L607). Are you sure your environment during manual invocation is *exactly* the same as under pytest?

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting `return_value` on a mocked function that is referenced by your recursive code, use `side_effect` instead.